# Unable to remove a div padding on all small screens with bootstrap 3 media query

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am making a template. I use bootstrap 3. I have a div just below my top navigation menu. I gave a padding-top:150px for the div. This looks fine for the normal screens but looks weird on small screens.

Now my question is how can I reduce the padding-top of my div using bootstrap media query. The below is what I tried and not working.

```css
#homepage-banner-content{
    margin-top:150px;
}

/* Small screen */

@media (max-width: 375px) {
    
    #homepage-banner-content
        margin-top:0px;
    }
}
```

I want to remove this 150px padding on all mobile screens. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by this,

```
/* Small screen */
@media (max-width: 375px) {         
    #homepage-banner-content{
        margin-top:0px;
    }
}
```

you just missed a **Curly brackets**. Be ensure that you added meta **viewport** in head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Simple typo, you missed a `{` after your `#homepage-banner-content` selector. Happens to the best of us.

```
#homepage-banner-content{
    margin-top:150px;
}

/* Small screen */

@media (max-width: 375px) {

    #homepage-banner-content { /* here */
        margin-top:0px;
    }
}
```